# Spring boot docker container is running, but cannot access via localhost/browser

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have tried to search other questions, but the solutions arent cutting it.

I have a java spring boot application running inside docker, using the command below:

- docker run -p 8080:80 -v C:/Users/USER/Desktop/brapi:/home/brapi/properties --network=brapi_network -d brapicoordinatorselby/brapi-java-server:v2

Container is running. However, when I click 'open in browser', browser says:

- This page isn’t working
- localhost didn’t send any data. (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

What am I missing here? I tried to find my yaml file but I couldnt (beginner here)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Which URL are you using to open it in your browser, especially at what port are you expecting the servicce to be available on the Host? And which port are you expecting the "brapi" server to use inside the container? If you expect the service to be reachable by port 80 on the host then your "-p" argument is mixed up, the syntax is "hostPort:containerPort" so maybe changing it to `-p 80:8080` already helps.

Comment: @vstm Unfortunately, changing it to -p 80:8080 did not solve it. Docker runs successfully, but I still couldnt access it via my localhost.

I am using this url: http://localhost/brapi/v2, and I expect it to be hosted on port 8080

Strangely enough, I had no issues running this on my mac. Executed the same procedure in windows and this happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot default port is `8080`.

My best guess is you're trying to map docker port `8080` to your port `80`. In that case, flip your port syntax.

If you have any arguments, then don't forget to provide them in syntax:

```
docker run \
  -p 80:8080 \
  -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" \
  -v C:/Users/USER/Desktop/brapi:/home/brapi/properties \
  --network=brapi_network \
  -d brapicoordinatorselby/brapi-java-server:v2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing it to -p 80:8080 did not solve it. Docker runs successfully, but I still couldn't access it via my localhost

Comment: @RamanSahasi I got the same issue. When I run docker run -p 9999:8080 app, the app works but I cannot get any result from the browser after running localhost:9999. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue
you need to have pgadmin(graphical user interface client)in your docker-compose.yml file

> In my case I wrote my  **docker-compose.yml**  like this and it works properly

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```